# Extending functionality of existing program I don't have source for

Tags: windows, winapi, hook, reverse-engineering

I'm working on a third-party program that aggregates data from a bunch of different, existing Windows programs.  Each program has a mechanism for exporting the data via the GUI.  The most brain-dead approach would have me generate extracts by using AutoIt or some other GUI manipulation program to generate the extractions via the GUI.  The problem with this is that people might be interacting with the computer when, suddenly, some automated program takes over.  That's no good.  What I really want to do is somehow have a program run once a day and silently (i.e. without popping up any GUIs) export the data from each program.

My research is telling me that I need to hook each application (assume these applications are always running) and inject a custom DLL to trigger each export.  Am I remotely close to being on the right track?  I'm a fairly experienced software dev, but I don't know a whole lot about reverse engineering or hooking.  Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:  I'm trying to manage the availability of a certain type of professional.  Their schedules are stored in proprietary systems.  With their permission, I want to install an app on their system that extracts their schedule from whichever system they are using and uploads the information to a central server so that I can present that information to potential clients.

Comment: I'm going to ask for clarification... You want to *silently*, several times a day, extract information from other applications that the user is running and export it somewhere? Isn't that the definition of malware/spyware? I'd think if you did this, AV or spyware detection apps would be on to you pretty quickly. I also think that, if you're going to expect to get help here, you're going to have to edit your question to provide details about why exactly you need to do this, or your question will be closed for being unwelcome here.

Comment: Check [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10096071/960757) for instance. Anyway doesn't have the *AutoIT* or similar a possibility to hide the target app window after you run it ?

Comment: TLama, that wouldn't be good enough.  The ideal solution needs to not pop up the target app window at all.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Given that you would need to partially reverse engineer each application individually in order to determine what to mess about with, have you investigated accessing the underlying storage system used by these apps? Most scheduling programs will run of off some kind of database like mechanic

Comment: I can't imagine that anyone would willingly install such an app.  I have the same reservations as @KenWhite.

Comment: @MartinJames: Greg clarified the purpose in an edit (the final paragraph), where the use sounds more reasonable than the original question did, and he does mention "with their permission". :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am aware of four ways of extracting the information you want, both with their advantages and disadvantages. Before you do anything, you need to be aware that any solution you create is not guaranteed and in fact very unlikely to continue working should the target application ever update. The reason is that in each case, you are relying on an **implementation detail** instead of a pre-defined interface through which to export your data.

## Hooking the GUI

The first way is to hook the GUI as you have suggested. What you are doing in this case is simply reading off from what an actual user would see. This is in general easier, since you are hooking the WinAPI which is clearly defined. One danger is that what the program displays is inconsistent or incomplete in comparison to the internal data it is supposed to be representing.

Typically, there are two common ways to perform WinAPI hooking:

- DLL Injection. You create a DLL which you load into the other program's virtual address space. This means that you have read/write access (writable access can be gained with [VirtualProtect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) to the target's entire memory. From here you can trampoline the functions which are called to set UI information. For example, to check if a window has changed its text, you might trampoline the [SetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Note every [control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) has different interfaces used to set what they are displaying. In this case, you are hooking the functions called by the code to set the display.
- [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Under the covers, this works similarly to DLL injection and in this case is really just another method for you to extend/subvert the control flow of messages received by controls. What you want to do in this case is hook the window procedures of each child control. For example, when an item is added to a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it would receive a [CB_ADDSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775828%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. In this case, you are hooking the messages that are received when the display changes.

One caveat with this approach is that it will only work if the target is using or extending WinAPI controls.

## Reading from the GUI

Instead of hooking the GUI, you can alternatively use WinAPI to read directly from the target windows. However, in some cases this may not be allowed. There is not much to do in this case but to try and see if it works. This may in fact be the easiest approach. Typically, you will send messages such as [WM_GETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to query the target window for what it is currently displaying. To do this, you will need to obtain the exact window hierarchy containing the control you are interested in. For example, say you want to read an edit control, you will need to see what parent window/s are above it in the window hierarchy in order to obtain its window handle.

## Reading from memory (Advanced)

This approach is by far the most complicated but if you are able to fully reverse engineer the target program, it is the most likely to get you consistent data. This approach works by you reading the memory from the target process. This technique is very commonly used in game hacking to add 'functionality' and to observe the internal state of the game.

Consider that as well as storing information in the GUI, programs often hold their own internal model of all the data. This is especially true when the controls used are [virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Virtual_ListView_Style) and simply query subsets of the data to be displayed. This is an example of a situation where the first two approaches would not be of much use. This data is often held in some sort of abstract data type such as a list or perhaps even an array. The trick is to find this list in memory and read the values off directly. This can be done externally with [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or internally through DLL injection again. The difficulty lies mainly in two prerequisites:

- Firstly, you must be able to reliably locate these data structures. The problem with this is that code is not guaranteed to be in the same place, especially with features such as [ASLR](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista.aspx). Colloquially, this is sometimes referred to as code-shifting. ASLR can be defeated by using the offset from a module base and dynamically getting the module base address with functions such as [GetModuleHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As well as ASLR, a reason that this occurs is due to dynamic memory allocation (e.g. through `malloc`). In such cases, you will need to find a heap address storing the pointer (which would for example be the return of `malloc`), dereference that and find your list. That pointer would be prone to ASLR and instead of a pointer, it might be a double-pointer, triple-pointer, etc.
- The second problem you face is that it would be rare for each list item to be a primitive type. For example, instead of a list of character arrays (strings), it is likely that you will be faced with a list of objects. You would need to further reverse engineer each object type and understand internal layouts (at least be able to determine offsets of primitive values you are interested in in terms of its offset from the object base). More advanced methods revolve around actually reverse engineering the [vtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301398.aspx) of objects and calling their 'API'.

You might notice that I am not able to give information here which is specific. The reason is that by its nature, using this method requires an intimate understanding of the target's internals and as such, the specifics are defined only by how the target has been programmed. Unless you have knowledge and experience of reverse engineering, it is unlikely you would want to go down this route.

## Hooking the target's internal API (Advanced)

As with the above solution, instead of digging for data structures, you dig for the internal API. I briefly covered this with when discussing vtables earlier. Instead of doing this, you would be attempting to find internal APIs that are called when the GUI is modified. Typically, when a view/UI is modified, instead of directly calling the WinAPI to update it, a program will have its own wrapper function which it calls which in turn calls the WinAPI. You simply need to find this function and hook it. Again this is possible, but requires reverse engineering skills. You may find that you discover functions which you want to call yourself. In this case, as well as being able to locate the location of the function, you have to reverse engineer the parameters it takes, its calling convention and you will need to ensure calling the function has no side effects.

I would consider this approach to be advanced. It can certainly be done and is another common technique used in game hacking to observe internal states and to manipulate a target's behaviour, but is difficult!

---

The first two methods are well suited for reading data from WinAPI programs and are by far easier. The two latter methods allow greater flexibility. With enough work, you are able to read **anything and everything** encapsulated by the target but requires a lot of skill.

Another point of concern which may or may not relate to your case is how easy it will be to update your solution to work should the target every be updated. With the first two methods, it is more likely no changes or small changes have to be made. With the second two methods, even a small change in source code can cause a relocation of the offsets you are relying upon. One method of dealing with this is to use byte signatures to dynamically generate the offsets. I wrote [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9644717/find-a-function-by-it-signature-in-windows-dll/9646320#9646320) some time ago which addresses how this is done.

What I have written is only a brief summary of the various techniques that can be used for what you want to achieve. I may have missed approaches, but these are the most common ones I know of and have experience with. Since these are large topics in themselves, I would advise you ask a new question if you want to obtain more detail about any particular one. Note that in all of the approaches I have discussed, none of them suffer from any interaction which is visible to the outside world so you would have no problem with anything popping up. It would be, as you describe, 'silent'.

---

This is relevant information about detouring/trampolining which I have lifted from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865423/how-to-detect-hidden-processes/8865477#8865477) I wrote:

> If you are looking for ways that programs detour execution of other
> processes, it is usually through one of two means:
>
> - Dynamic (Runtime) Detouring - This is the more common method and is what is used by libraries such as [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/68568/huntusenixnt99.pdf). Here is a
>   relevant paper where the first few bytes of a function are overwritten
>   to unconditionally branch to the instrumentation.
> - (Static) Binary Rewriting - This is a much less common method for rootkits, but is used by research projects. It allows detouring to be
>   performed by statically analysing and overwriting a binary. An old
>   (not publicly available) package for Windows that performs this is
>   Etch. [This paper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/alecw/usenix-nt-1997.pdf) gives a high-level view of how it works
>   conceptually.
>
> Although Detours demonstrates one method of dynamic detouring, there
> are countless methods used in the industry, especially in the reverse
> engineering and hacking arenas. These include the IAT and breakpoint
> methods I mentioned above. To 'point you in the right direction' for
> these, you should look at 'research' performed in the fields of
> research projects and reverse engineering.